# Terraform - Duplicate Output Definition, but there is no Duplicate Outputs

Tags: terraform

I had a terraform `main.tf` file where I previously added outputs e.g.

```
output "ids" {
  value       = some_resource.name.value
  description = something 
}
```

I have now moved the above block to a separate `outputs.tf` file for cleanliness. But I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Duplicate output definition

  on modules/my/outputs.tf line 1:
  11: output "ids" {

An output named "ids" was already defined at modules/my/main.tf:11,1-13.
Output names must be unique within a module.
```

This doesn't make any sense. Is this something like a local cache messup? Or, am I not allowed to do this refactoring (I'm sure I can)...? I am using version 0.14.4

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Have you saved the changes before trying? Or maybe your code runs in some CICD pipeline and you haven't committed changes to main.tf yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. The editor I was using was Visual Studio Code. And this just doesn't always reflect the changes correctly. I have pressed `CTRL + S` numerous times, but always fails. I had to restart the editor a few times, and then it worked.

Comment: VSCode allows extensions to run actions on save, and some extensions use that to run time-consuming operations which can therefore delay the files actually being committed to disk. I've been caught out by that before too, although it was when working on Go rather than on Terraform. Might be worth looking through which extensions you have enabled to see if you have any formatting or similar ones that might take actions on save; disabling one of them might make your saving more reliable.

Comment: I have moved to IntelliJ IDEA since yesterday so.... :shrug:

Answer (score 0):

I moved all the output to main.tf , removed everything from outputs.tf and closed the editor twice ,reopened & applied changes via terraform apply -refresh=false. To me it worked.